# Javascript slider - images not loading

Tags: javascript, scroll, slider

I'm trying to create a similar grainy transition on scroll as here - https://codepen.io/ReGGae/pen/bmyYEj.

The issue I'm facing is that when trying to link images in JavaScript:
this.images [ 'images/1.jpg', 'images/2.jpg', 'images/3.jpg], they are not loading/appearing on the actual website. The background is all black. I have a very limited JavaScript knowledge so any solution will be appreciated. Only api links work as below. Thanks in advance.

JS code snippet:

```
    class Slider {
      constructor() {
        this.bindAll()
        
        this.vert = `
        varying vec2 vUv;
        void main() {
          vUv = uv;
          gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
        `
    
        this.frag = `
        varying vec2 vUv;
    
        uniform sampler2D texture1;
        uniform sampler2D texture2;
        uniform sampler2D disp;
    
        uniform float dispPower;
        uniform float intensity;
    
        uniform vec2 size;
        uniform vec2 res;
    
        vec2 backgroundCoverUv( vec2 screenSize, vec2 imageSize, vec2 uv ) {
          float screenRatio = screenSize.x / screenSize.y;
          float imageRatio = imageSize.x / imageSize.y;
          vec2 newSize = screenRatio < imageRatio 
              ? vec2(imageSize.x * (screenSize.y / imageSize.y), screenSize.y)
              : vec2(screenSize.x, imageSize.y * (screenSize.x / imageSize.x));
          vec2 newOffset = (screenRatio < imageRatio 
              ? vec2((newSize.x - screenSize.x) / 2.0, 0.0) 
              : vec2(0.0, (newSize.y - screenSize.y) / 2.0)) / newSize;
          return uv * screenSize / newSize + newOffset;
        }
    
        void main() {
          vec2 uv = vUv;
          
          vec4 disp = texture2D(disp, uv);
          vec2 dispVec = vec2(disp.x, disp.y);
          
          vec2 distPos1 = uv + (dispVec * intensity * dispPower);
          vec2 distPos2 = uv + (dispVec * -(intensity * (1.0 - dispPower)));
          
          vec4 _texture1 = texture2D(texture1, distPos1);
          vec4 _texture2 = texture2D(texture2, distPos2);
          
          gl_FragColor = mix(_texture1, _texture2, dispPower);
        }
        `
        
        this.el = document.querySelector('.js-slider')
        this.inner = this.el.querySelector('.js-slider__inner')
        this.slides = [...this.el.querySelectorAll('.js-slide')]
        this.bullets = [...this.el.querySelectorAll('.js-slider-bullet')]
        
        this.renderer = null
        this.scene = null
        this.clock = null
        this.camera = null
        
        this.images = [
          'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg1.jpg',
          'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg2.jpg',
          'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg3.jpg'
        ]
        
        this.data = {
          current: 0,
          next: 1,
          total: this.images.length - 1,
          delta: 0
        }
        
        this.state = {
          animating: false,
          text: false,
          initial: true
        }
        
        this.textures = null
        
        this.init()
      }
      
      bindAll() {
        ['render', 'nextSlide']
        .forEach(fn => this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this))
      }
      
      setStyles() {
        this.slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
          if (index === 0) return
          
          TweenMax.set(slide, { autoAlpha: 0 })
        })
        
        this.bullets.forEach((bullet, index) => {
          if (index === 0) return
          
          const txt = bullet.querySelector('.js-slider-bullet__text')
          const line = bullet.querySelector('.js-slider-bullet__line')
          
          TweenMax.set(txt, {
            alpha: 0.25
          })
          TweenMax.set(line, {
            scaleX: 0,
            transformOrigin: 'left'
          })
        })
      }
      
      cameraSetup() {
        this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
          this.el.offsetWidth / -2,
          this.el.offsetWidth / 2,
          this.el.offsetHeight / 2,
          this.el.offsetHeight / -2,
          1,
          1000
        )
    
        this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position)
        this.camera.position.z = 1
      }
    
      setup() {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene()
        this.clock = new THREE.Clock(true)
        
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true })
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
        this.renderer.setSize(this.el.offsetWidth, this.el.offsetHeight)
        
        this.inner.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
      }
      
      loadTextures() {
        const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
        loader.crossOrigin = ''
        
        this.textures = []
        this.images.forEach((image, index) => {
          const texture = loader.load(image + '?v=' + Date.now(), this.render)
          
          texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
          texture.generateMipmaps = false
          
          if (index === 0 && this.mat) {
            this.mat.uniforms.size.value = [
              texture.image.naturalWidth,
              texture.image.naturalHeight
            ]
          }
    
          this.textures.push(texture)
        })
        
        this.disp = loader.load('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/rock-_disp.png', this.render)
        this.disp.magFilter = this.disp.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
        this.disp.wrapS = this.disp.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
      }
      
      createMesh() {
        this.mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
          uniforms: {
            dispPower: { type: 'f', value: 0.0 },
            intensity: { type: 'f', value: 0.5 },
            res: { value: new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) },
            size: { value: new THREE.Vector2(1, 1) },
            texture1: { type: 't', value: this.textures[0] },
            texture2: { type: 't', value: this.textures[1] },
            disp: { type: 't', value: this.disp }
          },
          transparent: true,
          vertexShader: this.vert,
          fragmentShader: this.frag
        })
    
        const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(
          this.el.offsetWidth, 
          this.el.offsetHeight, 
          1
        )
        
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, this.mat)
    
        this.scene.add(mesh)    
      }
      
      transitionNext() {
        TweenMax.to(this.mat.uniforms.dispPower, 2.5, {
          value: 1,
          ease: Expo.easeInOut,
          onUpdate: this.render,
          onComplete: () => {
            this.mat.uniforms.dispPower.value = 0.0
            this.changeTexture()
            this.render.bind(this)
            this.state.animating = false
          }
        })
        
        const current = this.slides[this.data.current]
        const next = this.slides[this.data.next]
        
        const currentImages = current.querySelectorAll('.js-slide__img')
        const nextImages = next.querySelectorAll('.js-slide__img')
        
        const currentText = current.querySelectorAll('.js-slider__text-line div')
        const nextText = next.querySelectorAll('.js-slider__text-line div')
        
        const currentBullet = this.bullets[this.data.current]
        const nextBullet = this.bullets[this.data.next]
        
        const currentBulletTxt = currentBullet.querySelectorAll('.js-slider-bullet__text')
        const nextBulletTxt = nextBullet.querySelectorAll('.js-slider-bullet__text')
        
        const currentBulletLine = currentBullet.querySelectorAll('.js-slider-bullet__line')
        const nextBulletLine = nextBullet.querySelectorAll('.js-slider-bullet__line')
        
        const tl = new TimelineMax({ paused: true })
        
        if (this.state.initial) {
          TweenMax.to('.js-scroll', 1.5, {
            yPercent: 100,
            alpha: 0,
            ease: Power4.easeInOut
          })
          
          this.state.initial = false
        }
        
        tl
        .staggerFromTo(currentImages, 1.5, {
          yPercent: 0,
          scale: 1
        }, {
          yPercent: -185,
          scaleY: 1.5,
          ease: Expo.easeInOut
        }, 0.075)
        .to(currentBulletTxt, 1.5, {
          alpha: 0.25,
          ease: Linear.easeNone
        }, 0)
        .set(currentBulletLine, {
          transformOrigin: 'right'
        }, 0)
        .to(currentBulletLine, 1.5, {
          scaleX: 0,
          ease: Expo.easeInOut
        }, 0)
        
        if (currentText) {
          tl
          .fromTo(currentText, 2, {
            yPercent: 0
          }, {
            yPercent: -100,
            ease: Power4.easeInOut
          }, 0)  
        }
        
        tl
        .set(current, {
          autoAlpha: 0
        })
        .set(next, {
          autoAlpha: 1
        }, 1)
        
        if (nextText) {
          tl
          .fromTo(nextText, 2, {
            yPercent: 100
          }, {
            yPercent: 0,
            ease: Power4.easeOut
          }, 1.5)  
        }
        
        tl
        .staggerFromTo(nextImages, 1.5, {
          yPercent: 150,
          scaleY: 1.5
        }, {
          yPercent: 0,
          scaleY: 1,
          ease: Expo.easeInOut
        }, 0.075, 1)
        .to(nextBulletTxt, 1.5, {
          alpha: 1,
          ease: Linear.easeNone
        }, 1)
        .set(nextBulletLine, {
          transformOrigin: 'left'
        }, 1)
        .to(nextBulletLine, 1.5, {
          scaleX: 1,
          ease: Expo.easeInOut
        }, 1)
        
        tl.play()
      }
      
      prevSlide() {
        
      }
      
      nextSlide() {
        if (this.state.animating) return
        
        this.state.animating = true
        
        this.transitionNext()
        
        this.data.current = this.data.current === this.data.total ? 0 : this.data.current + 1
        this.data.next = this.data.current === this.data.total ? 0 : this.data.current + 1
      }
      
      changeTexture() {
        this.mat.uniforms.texture1.value = this.textures[this.data.current]
        this.mat.uniforms.texture2.value = this.textures[this.data.next]
      }
     
      listeners() {
        window.addEventListener('wheel', this.nextSlide, { passive: true })
      }
      
      render() {
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
      }
      
      init() {
        this.setup()
        this.cameraSetup()
        this.loadTextures()
        this.createMesh()
        this.setStyles()
        this.render()
        this.listeners()
      }
    }
    
    // Toggle active link
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.js-nav a')
    
    links.forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        links.forEach(other => other.classList.remove('is-active'))
        link.classList.add('is-active')
      })
    })
    
    // Init classes
    const slider = new Slider()
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. You have provided a class only, but it's not complete. Can you click on the snippet button and add a reproducible example? Currently I can only see that you created a `this.images` array and you refer to its length - 1 to the `total` of `this.data`, but I see no other use of it.

Comment: Hi, added the whole js code.